# Реализация живого поиска

Tags: javascript, html, css

есть список и форма ввода(код приложил ниже):

```js
function someFunc() {
  var noh = document.getElementById("search").value;
  spsk = document.getElementById(listr);
  spsk.style.display = 'none'
}
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = someFunc;
```

```css
.list li:nth-child {
  display: none;
}

input[type=button] {
  width: 120px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="srch" id="search" onchange=""> <input type="button" id="btn" value="сортировать">
<ol class="list" id="listr">
  <li>Саратов</li>
  <li>Новгород</li>
  <li>Москва</li>
  <li>Санкт-Петербург</li>
</ol>
```

Задача стоит следующая:
Имеется список в HTML, любой, маркированный или упорядоченный, при вводе символа(или части ключевого слова) необходимо удалить части списка, которые не относятся к ним, то есть если имея список приложенный в коде написать в строку ввода "м", то останется только Москва, а все остальные части списка нужно удалить, а если же строка ввода будет очищена, список вернётся в исходное положение.

Вопросы следующие:
 1. Как обрабатывать строку ввода и что в этом может помочь? То есть, если я ввожу и у меня в режиме реального времени удаляется часть списка, значит моё значение должно где-то временно храниться(я и пытался его хранить, что видно по коду JS), а потом каким-то образом взаимодействовать со списком, если это так, то каким образом я могу убрать часть списка при вводе определённого символа(через что это реализуется и каким конкретно образом)? Если же значение вводимое в строку нет необходимости сохранять, то каким образом ещё можно реализовать действие "при изменении сделать"?

Прошу помощи в решении данной задачи, потому как интернет внятных ответов не даёт, но утверждается что это задача "на 10-30 минут", на что я уже убил более двух часов. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `document.getElementById(listr)` - Здесь у вас опечатка

Comment: Погуглите HTML-элемент `<datalist>` в любом современном онлайн-справочнике.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь то, что Вам нужно.

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=\"text\"]").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("ul li")].forEach(item => {
    if (item.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())) {
      item.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      item.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<ul>
  <li>Москва</li>
  <li>Санкт-Петербург</li>
  <li>Киев</li>
  <li>Волгоград</li>
  <li>Челябинск</li>
  <li>Чебоксары</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Именно то, что нужно, однако есть ряд вопросов, не могли бы вы подробнее разъяснять, что именно происходит в описанных вами в javascript функциях? Что такое item.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(e.targer.value.toLowerCase()))?
Что означает символ =>
и квадратная скобка [... ?

Comment: `item.textContent` - берем текст из `<li>`, `toLowerCase()` - переводим всё в нижний регистр `*строка1*.includes(*строка2*)` - проверка, находится ли подстрока *строка2* в строке *строка1*, про => прочитайте [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp), `[...]` - просто выбрал все элементы `li` без записи в переменную(грубо говоря, поищите в интернете), если возникнут сложности - напишите, найду время связаться с Вами.